# node degree query on Neo4j with huge graph ( million nodes and links)

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, gremlin

How can I get the degree of every single node on Neo4j, and then find out which node has the biggest degree in a very huge graph (2 million nodes and 5 million relationships)?

I know I can use Cypher or Gremlin to achieve that, like:

```
start n = node(*) 
match (n)--(c)
return n, count(*) as connections
order by connections dsec
```

or

```
g.V.bothE
```

but the RAM my computer have is only 2G~4G, I always wait for a long time and get "undefined" when I issue the query above..

does anyone have some experience on query such huge graph on neo4j with gremlin or cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the biggest degree, you should also limit the result, so cypher will only have to keep the top 10 results.

```
START n = node(*) 
MATCH (n)--(c)
RETURN n, count(*) as connections
ORDER BY connections DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Or you could do:

```
START n = node(*)
RETURN n, length((n)--(c)) as connections
ORDER BY connections DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Otherwise I agree with Stefan.

Today you can also use `call apoc.stats.degrees('TYPE')` 
where `TYPE` is the relationship type, you can also pass `null` or `<TYPE` or `TYPE>` with direction.
This procedure is implemented in parallel and works well for large graphs.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I totally forget "LIMIT".
Anyway, thank you two a lot.

Comment: By the way, I wanna know if there is some node with no link, then what would be the result if I order by ascend? Would it show '0' or just skip it?

Comment: In the second command, i get syntax error in line 2 near `(c)`, it works if you replace it with `()`. You don't need it's name

Answer (score 1):

That is in fact a very expensive, global operation. In this case you might be better off using a [unmanaged extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) that uses [`GlobalGraphOperations.getAllRelationships`](http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.2/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllRelationships%28%29). During iterating all relationships you build up a Map and increment the counter for start and end node of each relationship. Final step is to find the maximum within your map.